Replacing select condition with jq's `IN`
Given the simplified input:
[
  [ "gpu" ],
  [ "disk" ]
]

I would like to select the arrays for which the first element is "gpu".
I can do it with a simple condition:
map(select(.[0] == "gpu"))

[
  [ "gpu" ]
]

But I don't understand what's wrong when I try to use the IN builtin instead:
map(select(.[0] | IN(["gpu"])))

[]

I'm using jq 1.6

IN/1 is defined as def IN(s): any(s == .; .);, so map(select(.[0] | IN(["gpu"]))) translates to map(select(.[0] | any(["gpu"] == .; .))) but . inside the map is [ "gpu" ], thus .[0] is "gpu", which is not equal to [ "gpu" ], and the filter consequently fails.
Instead, compare .[0] with "gpu":
map(select(.[0] | IN("gpu")))

[
  [
    "gpu"
  ]
]

Demo
Using IN, however, only makes sense for compacting multiple comparisons. For this single comparison, of course, a simple map(select(.[0] == "gpu")) would suffice.

Thanks. So if I want to check that .[0] is in a list of strings (which is in fact my goal), I should use .[0] | IN("str1", "str2", "str3", etc...) right?

@Fravadona Yes, you provide a stream of values. Due to the internal translation to any, this acts as a disjunction (or).

BTW, it's kind of harduous to search for IN in the doc, but it is listed in the "SQL-Style Operators" section (I managed to find it thanks to the source code link you provided ;-) )

Listing IN, INDEX, and JOIN collectively under SQL-Style Operators is indeed somewhat unfortunate, but for the general case, the top right search box (reachable by key binding /) provides autocompletion as you type.
